# undefined reference errors in C++

Tags: c++, include, linker, header-files

I have files Record.h and Record.cpp. When I just include the Record.h file, I get several undefined reference errors to functions defined in those files. When I also include Record.cpp then the errors go away. Why is that? Record.h has the forward declarations for the functions it says are an undefined reference.

Record.h

```
#ifndef RECORD_
#define RECORD_

#include <string>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

#define PKEYSIZE 10
#define STREETNUMSIZE 8
#define STREETNAMESIZE 24
#define RNAMESIZE 30
#define ASTYLESIZE 20
#define YEARSIZE 12

#define MAXBUCKETSIZE 4
#define MAXDIRECTORYSIZE 100

typedef struct
{

        char streetNum[STREETNUMSIZE];
        char streetName[STREETNAMESIZE];
        char rName[RNAMESIZE];
        char aStyle[ASTYLESIZE];
        char year[YEARSIZE];
        char pkey[PKEYSIZE];

} RECORD;

typedef struct
{
    int size;
    int depth;
    RECORD record[MAXBUCKETSIZE];

} BUCKET;


#define HEADERSIZE 2L

#define NODESIZE sizeof(BUCKET)

void addKey(RECORD *rec_ptr, string key);
void addStreetNum(RECORD *rec_ptr, string s);
void addStreetName(RECORD *rec_ptr, string s);
void addRName(RECORD *rec_ptr, string s);
void addAStyle(RECORD *rec_ptr, string s);
void addYear(RECORD *rec_ptr, string s);
void printRecord(RECORD *rec_ptr);
ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, RECORD *r);

string cvt_binary(unsigned int input);
void addRecord(RECORD *r);
void showbucket(int n);

#endif
```

Record.cpp

```
int dirDepth = 0;
int numberOfBuckets = 0;
int directory[MAXDIRECTORYSIZE];
BUCKET bucket[MAXDIRECTORYSIZE/MAXBUCKETSIZE];

void addKey(RECORD *rec_ptr, string key)
{
    strncpy(rec_ptr->pkey, key.c_str(), PKEYSIZE);

}

void addStreetNum(RECORD *rec_ptr, string s)
{
    strncpy(rec_ptr->streetNum, s.c_str(), STREETNUMSIZE);
}

void addStreetName(RECORD *rec_ptr, string s)
{
    strncpy(rec_ptr->streetName, s.c_str(), STREETNAMESIZE);
}

void addRName(RECORD *rec_ptr, string s)
{
    strncpy(rec_ptr->rName, s.c_str(), RNAMESIZE);
}

void addAStyle(RECORD *rec_ptr, string s)
{
    strncpy(rec_ptr->aStyle, s.c_str(), ASTYLESIZE);
}


void addYear(RECORD *rec_ptr, string s)
{
    strncpy(rec_ptr->year, s.c_str(), YEARSIZE);
}

void printRecord(RECORD *rec_ptr)
{

    cout<< "|"
        << rec_ptr->pkey << "|" 
        << rec_ptr->streetNum << "|" 
        << rec_ptr->streetName << "|" 
        << rec_ptr->rName << "|" 
        << rec_ptr->aStyle << "|" 
        << rec_ptr->year << endl;

}


ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, RECORD *r)
{
    out << r->pkey << r->streetNum << r->streetName << r->rName
        << r->aStyle << r->year << endl;
    return out;

}

int bucketread(short rrn, BUCKET *page_ptr)
{
//  long lseek(), addr;
    long addr;

    addr = (long)rrn * (long)NODESIZE + HEADERSIZE;
    lseek(btfd, addr, 0);
    return ( read(btfd, page_ptr, NODESIZE) );
}

int bucketwrite(short rrn, BUCKET *page_ptr)
{
//    long lseek(), addr;
    long addr;
    addr = (long) rrn * (long) NODESIZE + HEADERSIZE;
    lseek(btfd, addr, 0);
    return (write(btfd, page_ptr, NODESIZE));
}

void showbucket(int n)
{
    cout << "loading bucket " << n << endl;
    BUCKET b;
    bucketread(n, &b);
    cout << "there are " << b.size << " records in the bucket" << endl;

}

string cvt_binary(unsigned int input) {
    if(input == 0) return "0"; // trivial case
    string result;
    for(int i = numeric_limits<unsigned int>::digits - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if(input & (1 << i)) 
        {
            result += "1";
        } 
        else 
        {
            if(!result.empty()) result += "0";
        }
    }
    return result;
}


string hash (char* key)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int len = strlen(key);
    if (len % 2 == 1) len++; // make len even
    //for an odd length string, use the trailing 0 as part of key
    for (int j = 0; j < len; j +=2)
        sum = (sum + 100 * key[j] + key[j+1]) % 19937;
    return cvt_binary(sum);
}

void copyrecord(RECORD *dest, RECORD *src)
{
    cout << "copying record" << endl;
    addKey(dest, src->pkey);
    addStreetNum(dest, src->streetNum);
    addStreetName(dest, src->streetName);
    addRName(dest, src->rName);
    addAStyle(dest, src->aStyle);
    addYear(dest, src->year);
}

void addToBucket(int n, RECORD *r)
{
    cout << "Adding record " << r->pkey << " to bucket " << n << endl;
    if (bucket[n].size == MAXBUCKETSIZE)
    {
        cout << "Bucket " << n << " is full." << endl;
        // examine bucket depth and directory depth to determine next action
        cout << "Bucket depth: " << bucket[n].depth << endl;
        cout << "Directory depth: " << directory[0] << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        copyrecord(&bucket[n].record[bucket[n].size],r);
        bucket[n].size++;
        bucketwrite(1,&bucket[1]);


    }

}

string getreverse(string key, int num)
{
    if(num==0)
        return "";
    string newstring;
    newstring = key.at(key.length());
    newstring+= getreverse(key.substr(0,key.length()-1),num-1);

    return newstring;
}

void addRecord(RECORD *r)
{
    cout << r->pkey << endl;
    string hashvalue = hash(r->pkey);
    cout << "hash value is " << hashvalue << endl;

    int directoryDepth = directory[0];

    if(directoryDepth == 0)
    {
        directory[1] = 1;
        addToBucket(1, r);
    }
    else
    {
        // use hashing to figure out which bucket to add to
        cout << "The relevant string is" <<  getreverse(hashvalue, directoryDepth) << endl;

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm using g++ and it usually works correctly.

Comment: Please don't use `using namespace std;` in header files, only in implementation files.

Comment: Even in implementation files, it's better to only do it for the symbols you often use, bringing the whole namespace is never necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Record.h has the **declarations** of those functions. Record.cpp has the **definitions**.

```
//Record.h

void foo(); // This is a forward declaration
```

So far so good.

```
//main.cpp

#include "Record.h"

int main()
{
    foo();
}
```

Now main.o will compile just fine. But if you try to link it into a working binary, you'll get a complaint that `void foo()` is undefined.

```
//Record.cpp

#include "Record.h"

// This is the definition
void foo()
{
    // do various things
}
```

This can be compiled into Record.o, which can then be linked with main.o into a working executable.

Comment: `void foo();` is a _declaration_. The "forward" is meaningless, there is no other. It's `main.cpp` what is compiling fine, not `main.o`. If you fix these, I'd feel better about my up-vote.

Comment: @sbi: Since `void foo();` is a declaration of something that has not yet been defined (as far as main is concerned) it is by definition a forward declaration-- whether there are others doesn't matter. Actually it is g++ that is compiling (or maybe Phenom), and I have heard both the source file (main.cpp) and the object file (main.o) used as the subject of the ergative form of the verb-- I was going for clarity, but being a grammar nazi myself I would be glad to hear a well-reasoned argument for one over the other.

Comment: @Beta, re declarations that are or are not _forward_ declarations: What's a relevant practical case of a declaration __not__ being a _forward_ declaration? (Why declare something that's already defined, when, by definition, a definition is a declaration, too?) As for what a compiler compiles: My dish washer washes dirty dishes and produces clean ones. Likewise, my compiler compiles source files and produces object files.

Comment: @sbi: Declarations: I respectfully suggest that you have lost track of the point you are trying to make. Dishes: not a strong argument since 1) you are using "wash" as a transitive verb which makes it irrelevant, 2) we don't say "the dishes wash", and 3) one example doesn't make a case: we say "the bread is baking", not "the dough is baking".

Comment: @Beta: 1) "Forward" implies that it is declared _before-hand_, that is, _before the definition_. But what else are declarations for? If they appear _after_ the definition, they are _redeclarations_ (as every definition is a declaration, too). Usually declarations are used to declare something _before_ it is defined. They are all either _forward declarations_ or _redeclarations_. (BTW, the term _forward_ declaration I have only ever heard for classes, [where it is indeed meaningless, as there are no other forms of class declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/1410632#1410632).)

Comment: @Beta: 2) What I meant to say is that the act of processing usually refers to the input as what is processed upon (sorry if that sounds awkward, I'm not a native), but you have found a good counter example. Your answer is the very first time I ever heard that a compiler compiles object files, but, thinking about it, this might be because I'm a non-native, and have never thought about the verb's meaning outside of translating a program. So I retract and say that, yes, while I have never heard it, it might very well make sense to say it that way, I just wouldn't know. I'm sorry for that.

Comment: @sbi: I think we actually agree about declarations: my use of "forward" was technically correct but unneeded. As for "compile", I can think of examples on both sides but I can see no rule. I see that you are from Germany-- German is a more precise language than English, and maybe you have a clear rule for this, and maybe an English grammarian would say that "the source compiles" is correct, but I have heard both forms so I use whichever one seems to make things most clear at the time. (P.S. I meant no offense when I called myself a grammar nazi!)

Answer (score 3):

Providing the ***declarations*** by including the header is what the *compiler* needs. The *linker* needs the ***definitions***. It will find these in the object files the compiler creates when it compiles source files.
I'm not using gcc, but I think it can just be called with all the source files and will then call the linker with all the object files provided: `g++ main.cpp record.cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

My C++ might be a bit rusty, but it sounds like `Record.cpp` isn't being compiled into the solution. If the `.cpp` file isn't there, then the header has nothing to **refer** to. Don't include the cpp, but check your linker settings, or the command you're using to compile your program... it needs to include all the cpps.